# ssh to device via jump sever for interactive session

Tags: php

Problem:
There are 3 devices: My server (Linux), the jump server (Linux) and a Cisco box.
I can manually ssh onto the jump server and from there ssh to the Cisco box and run commands interactively.
Is there a way I can acheive this programatically using PHP?
I want to be able to interogate the responses from the Cisco box as I go and tailor the next commands accordingly.
I have done similar things in Python but was able to connect directly using socket (no jump server in between)
but I prefer using PHP if I can.

Comment: or google interactive php shell.

Comment: I have been Googling - php + ssh, ssh tunnel, port forwarding etc all day but haven't found anything that works.Practical suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

`man ssh`:

```
 -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
         arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
         very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Therefore, `ssh -t jump_server ssh -t cisco_box ...`

Also, you can use such command in PHP via [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) or [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Then you will have stdin, stdout, and stderr (along with other file descriptors) of the executed ssh available in PHP, so you can send/receive commands and data to/from the cisco box.

It depends on the program on the other end whether it needs tty or not (which `-t` enforces). Programs like mc do need tty, but most command line tools don't (then simply ommit the `-t`).

Comment: If this idea has any validity, how could I wrap it in PHP and then send commands and receive output. I'm sorry but I find it a little to vague for me to understand at this time.

Comment: After many unsuccessful attempts, I am now trying with Python. My new question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557671/how-do-i-capture-password-prompt

Comment: Try simpe use from shell, when it works, figure out how to call it from PHP.