# Passing data in script Python using subprocess for executable

Tags: python, windows, automation, executable

I am struggling with a challange in python. I have an idea that my script must evoke an executable file. I am able to pass this executable a username, but what comes to password I need to enter it manually in command line. I want to automate the application, so I dont enter it manually every time. Here is the script. I run it under Windows.

```
`
import subprocess 

p = subprocess.Popen(".\executable.exe --user domain\user", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

p.communicate(input="Mypassword")`
```

Comment: You could use pexpect. Pretty powerful tool for this type of automation.

Comment: Thank you, trying to run it with the pexpect I still get to the point where the executable pops out the request to input the password

Comment: Well then capture it and send it the password. That's the whole point of using pexpect. See examples in documentation or other stackoverflow questions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557671/how-do-i-capture-password-prompt